# Guarantee vs. invitor (visiting relatives from Philippines to Japan)

Tags: japan, tourist-visas, filipino-citizens

Should the guarantor and the invitee be the same?

Answer (score 1):

(Hi), there seem to be an inconsistency with your title and the actual content of your question, but I believe that what you are trying to ask is whether or not the guarantor should also be the invit**er**.

The short answer is "No". The long answer is "No, but I believe that the invitee (person being invited) or applicant will have a higher chance of getting his/her application approved if the guarantor is also the inviter."

The reason for the long answer is because, the applicant needs to submit an Invitation Letter from the Guarantor in Japan. See the [complete list of requirements for Visiting Relatives visa](https://www.ph.emb-japan.go.jp/files/000233961.pdf). If the inviter is the Gurantor, it means that s/he guarantees that the applicant is of good moral character, does not plan to overstay, etc. and in some cases also plan to shoulder part or all of the applicant's travel expenses.

You can get more information on Japanese visas from the website of the [Embassy of Japan in the Philippines](https://www.ph.emb-japan.go.jp/itpr_en/00_000035.html).

Comment: So I am inviting a family member and since I don't have a job (i just had one recently and it doesn't show in the income certificate) I had a friend who is willing to be a guarantor. I and my friend are both Japanese. I just sent the required papers today and I hope it goes out well?

Comment: I think that would be the case. Recently (since maybe 5 yrs ago) it has gotten relatively easier for Filipino citizens to visit Japan, so if all the papers are in order then I wouldn't worry too much about it.

Answer (score -2):

It can be the same but does not need to be

Comment: It would be better if you have some official sources.

Comment: The forms for guarantee letter and invitation letter https://www.mofa.go.jp/files/000137089.pdf      https://www.mofa.go.jp/j_info/visit/visa/pdfs/application2.pdf  it says (When an inviting person and a guarantor are the same, you may write “Same as guarantor”.)

Comment: But the agency says "7:INVITATION LETTER FROM GUARANTOR IN JAPAN"

Comment: What agency? Japan has no any official visa agencies. Your agency is just incompetent. You dont need any agency if going to Japanese consulate personally is not a problem.
It's common for friends being invited by someone who can not support because he is still child. And grantor is some parent.

Comment: @Rambalac The Japanese embassy in Manila requires all visa applications (except for special cases like diplomats, Japanese Government invitees, etc.) to go through accredited agencies. See embassy website link: https://www.ph.emb-japan.go.jp/itpr_en/00_000261.html

Comment: We are applying for a tourist visa (Visiting relatives) You need to apply to an agency that is accredited by the Bureau of immigration in the Philippines. I noticed that every agency have slight differences when it comes to required papers.